# Items in Flexbox parent DIV not centering

Tags: html, css, flexbox, absolute

My flex-items in the header (flex-parent) are refusing to center both vertically & horizontally. This is quite strange as I am an avid user of flex-box and I have never run into this problem before. I thought it was something to do with the absolute positioning, but even after removing this - the items are still not centered. I've tried everything and would appreciate some help please. Thank you.

**EDIT:** OK, so it seems the content is truly centered, and it is actually the distribution of letters in my list items that make it appear non-centered. Still very annoying though and not pleasing to the eye.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>            
    <header>
      <h2>LOGO</h2>
        <nav>
          <ul>
              <li>HOME</li>
              <li>EVENTS</li>
              <li>CONTACT</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
  <section id="section1">
      <h1>INDIGO NIGHTS</h1>
  </section>   
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* HEADER */
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color:white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:50px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

 ul li {
   display: inline;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
   list-style-type:none;
   padding-left:0.9em;
   padding-right:0.9em;
   font-size: 0.9em;
 }

 /* SECTION 1 */
#section1 {
  height:100vh;
  background-image: url("billboard.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size:5em;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 795px) {
  #section1 h1 { 
    font-size: 3.5em; 
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 630px) {
  #section1 h1 { 
    font-size: 3em; 
  }
}
```

[Demo link](http://jsbin.com/jonaqadebe/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I have included a demo link. Header content seems to alright. Kindly add more details like how do you want the elements to be positioned.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you want the li items to be centered, but ul is not a flex container

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding a min width to list items and aligning text to center:

```
ul li {
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or you can specify a `flex-basis` as `15%` (will allow 100/15 = 6 menu items in one line) to the list items with setting their container widths as `100%`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* SECTION 1 */

#section1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("billboard.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 795px) {
  #section1 h1 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 630px) {
  #section1 h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h2>LOGO</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>EVENTS</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="section1">
    <h1>INDIGO NIGHTS</h1>
  </section>
</body>
```